# sending image to server (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, canvas

React beginner here, i need to send an image which is taken by snapshot to a server, this image is in blob, how to send this to server should i change something because it is a blob ? so when button is cliked it should send it to server, any idea ?

English is not my mother language so could be mistakes

codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-screenshot-hook-forked-edzwox?file=/src/App.js

code:

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  const createScreenshot = () =>
    new Promise((resolve) => {
      canvasRef.current.toBlob((blob) => {
        const src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const image = new Image();
        image.onload = () => resolve(image);
        image.src = src;
        console.log("image", src);
      });
    });

  const takeSnapshott= () => {
    createScreenshot().then((image) => {
      document.body.append(image);
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!canvasRef.current) throw new Error("Ref is null");
    const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");

    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(20, 10, 150, 100);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "5px solid red" }}>
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }} />
      <button onClick={takeSnapshott}>Send this screenshot</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

my action:

```js
postData: function postData(endpoint: string, body: any, 
 returnType: string) {
return function (dispatch: Dispatch) {
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
body = JSON.stringify(body);
const init = { method: 'POST', body, headers };
return fetch(endpoint, init)
  .then((response) => {
    return handle_response(response, returnType);
  })
  .then((json) => {
    dispatch({ type: returnType, payload: json });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    handle_error(dispatch, err, endpoint, returnType);
  });
  };
}


export function takeSnapshot(site: string, camera: string) {
  return postData(
    `api/cameras/${site}/${camera}/snapshot`,
    {},
    ActionType.TAKE_SNAPSHOT,
  );
}
```

in my component:

```js
const takeSnapshott = () => {dispatch(takeSnapshot(currentSite.identifier, 
currentCamera.identifier)); );
```

Comment: any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your question is clear, but your code is not very clear:

- It seems you are using redux since your postData function is a Redux Thunk, but you are not dispatching it inside your react component.
- You are getting the canvas blob, then converting it to string, and create a new canvas Image from that string, then append it back , this does not make much sense to me.

This is a flow that would make sense to me:

```
function App() {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState("");

// This function retrieves the blob of the canvas image

  const getImage = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>
      canvasRef.current.toBlob((blob) => {
        const src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        setPreview(src);
        resolve(blob);
      })
    );
  };

 // This is the function that retrieves the image blob and sends it to the server

  const sendToServer = async () => {
    const blob = await getImage();
    // Append the blob to a formData instance
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", blob, "picture");
    try {
      const res = await fetch(_URL, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        },
        body: formData
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      if (res.ok) console.log("SUCCESS", data);
      else throw new Error(data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!canvasRef.current) throw new Error("Ref is null");
    const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.fillRect(20, 10, 150, 100);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ border: "5px solid red" }}>
      <span>Preview:</span>
      <span>
        {" "}
        <img src={preview} alt="preview" />
      </span>
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }} />
      <button onClick={sendToServer}>Send this screenshot</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Just make sure you set the right content type in the headers: `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"`. 
You could also post directly the blob in the body but in that case you need to specify the content type as undefined, so the it receives the right content type automatically `"Content-Type": "undefined"`.

Demo [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-screenshot-hook-forked-kl2nww?file=/src/App.js:719-767)

Comment: How am I supposed to read that stuff ? Add edits to your original post please.

Comment: Is it ok now, added to question?

Comment: So what's your current problem ? You have many mistakes in that code and typos, you need to pass the blob to your  thunk, but you are passing an empty object. You don't want to set content-type json, since you are sending a blob. Then you have this `takeSnapshott` function that dispatches your thunk, but you never call that in your code, you are using another `takeSnapshot" function.

Comment: i dont know how to send blob data to that thunk

Comment: You need to add another arguent to takeSnapshot function, pass it the blob, and pass it as the second param of postData thunk. You are actually passing an empty object `{}`.
But if you don't change the thunk as I showed you, it won't work, since you are sending a JSON and not a blob.

Comment: could you possibly give an answer, now that i put more code with thunk included, would appreciate